# Ubuntu 12.04 installation failed - terminated by signal 9 ( killed)

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, acer, usb-installation

I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 via USB on my Acer TravelMate x483, but the installation stopped and this is what is showing on the screen:

```
Udevd[261]: '/sbin/blkid -o udev -p /dev/sdb'[3102]terminated by signal 9 ( killed)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you were installing via `Bootable USB`, it would be that which showed that error. Either your USB disconnected accidentally or it is malfunctioned (i,e contains some error) or not made bootable in proper way.

Comment: Yes, you are right, i did install with USB.  Can i try with a LIVE DVD instead?

Comment: You can try to install with USB also but I suggest you to make bootable `USB` using `Startup Disk Creator` which is available in  Ubuntu by default. So for that you can refer to any friend who are using Ubuntu. Although it would be better to install using Live DVD.. ;)

Comment: Ok, i will take your suggestion and install with LIVE DVD, will post with the outcome.  Thank you again

Comment: i'm up and running 12.04 :)  installed with Live DVD.  THANK YOU AGAIN FOR YOUR HELP!  but, my mousepad doesn't work and i have tried Fn+F7 and still nothing.

Comment: Search for your problem, probably you'll get the solution. If not then you can launch a new question. Since this question is solved, I would like to post an answer and want from you to accept it. So that it will help others as well. and comments can be easily deleted later..

Answer (score 0):

If you were installing via `Bootable USB`, it would be that which showed that error. Either your USB disconnected accidentally or it is malfunctioned (i,e contains some error) or not made bootable in proper way.

You can try to install with USB also but I suggest you to make bootable USB using **Startup Disk Creator** which is available in Ubuntu by default. So for that you can refer to any friend who are using Ubuntu. Although it would be better to install using `Live DVD`.. ;)